# wordpress block to create a text box containing various text sizes and gaps

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to find a Wordpress block to achieve a text/headline layout like this:

[image]

The text contains various sizes and gaps. Is there sth out there or do I need to build this from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TinyMCE editor, just paste the below code to your script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" 
referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
</head>
<body>
   <textarea>Next, use our Get Started docs to setup Tiny!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```